# Looping if statements

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Im looking to make this loop after it asks them a question in this case ""What is 2+2?" then taking there input, Then the program should ask "Are you sure Y/N" if they awnser no i want it to go back to the start of this loop and allow them to redo the question. As it is i can't get this to loop and after this part works i will need to do 9 more questions in the same format

---

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
class Quiz
{
  public static void main (String[] args) 
  {
  int q1=0 , q2=0;
  boolean correct = false;
  char yn1='y';
  String q3 , q4;
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner( System.in );

        int count = 0 ;
        //Question 1 start
        while (correct == false) 
                { 
                    System.out.println("What is 2+2? ");
                    System.out.println("Choices:  0,2,4,8");
                    q1 = input1.nextInt(); //used after loop


                    System.out.println("Are You Sure? (y/n)");
                    char c = input1.next().charAt(0);              // Changed LINE
                    if (c=='y')                                    // Changed LINE
                    {
                        if ( q1 == 4)  //q1 was stated during loop
                            System.out.println("You were correct 2+2 = 4");

                        else
                            System.out.println("You were wrong");

                        break;                        
                    } 
                }
        //Question 2 start
                while (correct == false) 
                { 
                    System.out.println("how many legs does a legless cow have?");
                    System.out.println("Choices:  0,25,4,31");
                    q2 = input1.nextInt();


                    System.out.println("Are You Sure? (y/n)");
                    char c = input1.next().charAt(0);              
                    if (c=='y')                                    
                    {
                        if ( q2 == 0)  
                            System.out.println("You were correct, the cow has 0 legs");

                        else
                            System.out.println("You were wrong");

                    break;                        
                    } 
                }

        //Question 3 start
                while (correct == false) 
                { 
                    System.out.println("What is the capital city of Canada?");
                    System.out.println("Choices:  Toronto, Montreal, Vancouver, Ottawa (capitals count)");
                     q3 = input1.nextLine();


                    System.out.println("Are You Sure? (y/n)");
                    char c = input1.next().charAt(0);              
                    if (c=='y')                                    
                    {
                        if ( "Ottawa".equals(q3))  
                            System.out.println("You were correct, The capital is Ottawa");

                        else
                            System.out.println("You were wrong");

                    break;                        
                    } 
                }



    }
  }
```

A new problem has occurred i have used the one helpful example and may try to change it to an array later but not in till i get the basics working. all the Questions usings int work so far Ie.

```
          //Question 1 start
    while (correct == false) 
        { 
            System.out.println("What is 2+2? ");
            System.out.println("Choices:  0,2,4,8");
            q1 = input1.nextInt(); //used after loop


            System.out.println("Are You Sure? (y/n)");
            char c = input1.next().charAt(0);              // Changed LINE
            if (c=='y')                                    // Changed LINE
            {
                if ( q1 == 4)  //q1 was stated during loop
                    System.out.println("You were correct 2+2 = 4");

                else
                    System.out.println("You were wrong");

                break;                        
            } 
        }
```

But now i want to use a word awnser so i made a string and put it in instead of int but now instead of allowing input for q3 it skips to input of y/n i don't understand why all of a sudden it would do this yet the other questions work correctly with int.

```
while (correct == false) 
                { 
                    System.out.println("What is the capital city of Canada?");
                    System.out.println("Choices:  Toronto, Montreal, Vancouver, Ottawa (capitals count)");
                    String q3 = input1.nextLine();


                    System.out.println("Are You Sure? (y/n)");
                    char c = input1.next().charAt(0);              
                    if (c=='y')                                    
                    {
                        if ( "Ottawa".equals(q3))  
                            System.out.println("You were correct, The capital is Ottawa");

                        else
                            System.out.println("You were wrong");

                    break;                        
                    } 
                }
```

Im sorry if this hasn't been enough detail or is formated wrong and will be sure to fix it if it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to compile  your program.But I am  getting some errors:-

```
error: variable q1 might not have been initialized
```

According to what I understand from ur question.Here is the program u want:-

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class stack1
{
  public static void main (String[] args) 
  {
  int q1=0 , q2 , q3, q4, q5, q6 , q7 ,q8 ,q9 ,q10 , a ;
  boolean correct = false;
  char yn1='Y';

        Scanner input1 = new Scanner( System.in );

        int count = 0 ;
       while (correct == false) 
                { 
        System.out.println("What is 2+2? ");
        System.out.println("Choices:  0,2,4,8");
        q1 = input1.nextInt(); //used after loop


                System.out.println("Are You Sure? (Y/N)");
                char c = input1.next().charAt(0);              // Changed LINE
                if (c=='y')                                    // Changed LINE
                {
        System.out.println("Exiting the program");
               correct = true; //It should now stop the loop and carry on 
                     break;                        
                } 


                }


                if ( q1 == 4)  //q1 was stated during loop
                    System.out.println("You were correct 2+2 = 4");

                else

                    System.out.println("You were wrong");

              //Soon will add int score and add 1 each time its correct
              // will be using 9 more loops the exact same way



    }
  }
```

I have mentioned all the changed lines with comment '//changed line' .

Comment: Sweet thank you, I'm gonna use this method first and if i have extra time i will try the array the other guy has mentioned.

Comment: I tried using a string instead of an int (i posted it as an edit) and it's skipping to y/n input any ideas to solving this?

Comment: @Curtis Spence Thank you Curtis!. I will surely help in my next post. But try to accept the answer if your 1st question is solved, so that it may be helpful for others also.

Comment: @CurtisSpence :- So now you want to take a string(capital name) from the user and check whether it is right or wrong? Is that the same u want??

Answer (score 1):

When reading input, always use `q1 = Integer.parseInt(input1.nextLine());` (Even better, use the `BufferedReader` class). That way, your reading will work smoothly.

Secondly, you can place the `if (q1 == 4)` within the `if (yn1.equals("Y"))` statement. If the user has typed "Y" then set `correct = true;` to proceed to the next question. Further, if the user's answer is correct then increment the counter of right answers else print wrong. So the loop looks like this:

```
    while (correct == false) {
        System.out.println("What is 2+2? ");
        System.out.println("Choices:  0,2,4,8");
        q1 = Integer.parseInt(input1.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Are You Sure? (Y/N)");
        yn1 = input1.nextLine();
        if (yn1.equals("Y")) {
            correct = true;
            if (q1 == 4) {
                System.out.println("You were correct 2+2 = 4");
                count++;
            } else
                System.out.println("You were wrong");
        }
    }
```

A few things to look into:

- You print `"Choices:  0,2,4,8"`, but nothing stops the user to enter `3` or `3000`. Is the choices statement necessary? Then you'll need to check if the user has entered within that range or not also.
- Instead of copying & pasting this same loop n times, make use an an array. Have all questions & answers stored in some String array for now. Something like this:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
      boolean nextQ = false;
      while (nextQ == false) {
          System.out.println(questions[i]);
          String ans = input1.nextLine();
          System.out.println("Are You Sure? (Y/N)");
          yn = input1.nextLine();
          if (yn.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
              nextQ = true;
              if (ans.equals(answers[i])) {
                  System.out.println("You were correct " + questions[i]
                          + " = " + answers[i]);
                  count++;
              } else
                  System.out.println("You were wrong");
          }
      }
  }
  ```

I changed the boolean variable `correct` to `nextQ` to avoid confusion. Hope the sets you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer for the edited Question:-

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class stack2
{
  public static void main (String[] args) 
  {
  int q1=0 , q2 , q3, q4, q5, q6 , q7 ,q8 ,q9 ,q10 , a ;
  boolean correct = false;
  char yn1='Y';
  String s="";
System.out.println(s);
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner( System.in );

        int count = 0 ;
       while (correct == false) 
                { 
        System.out.println("What is the capital city of Canada?");
        System.out.println("Choices:  Toronto, Montreal, Vancouver, Ottawa (capitals count)");
        s  = input1.nextLine();
        System.out.println(s);  
                System.out.println("Are You Sure? (Y/N)");
                char c = input1.next().charAt(0);              // Changed LINE

        if (c=='y')                                    // Changed LINE
                {
        System.out.println("Exiting the program");
               correct = true; //It should now stop the loop and carry on 
                     break;                        
                } 
          if (s.equals("Ottawa"))  //q1 was stated during loop
                    System.out.println("You were correct, The capital is Ottawa");

                else

                    System.out.println("You were wrong");

                }




              //Soon will add int score and add 1 each time its correct
              // will be using 9 more loops the exact same way



    }
 }
```

Be careful while entering the input.It shoul be exactly "Ottawa". Best of luck

Comment: The compuler still for ome reason skips to the are you sure input